# Google test adapter for visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, googletest, test-explorer

I'm using google test adapter for gtest framework in visual studio 2015. But when I compile the project with tests nothing appears in test explorer of visual studio thought I get the correct test report in a console. I've tryed to compile the same tests as are in googletest/msvc, which are reported in test explorer, in a new project. I set the same projects' settings but still have no reaction in test explorer. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The project name containing your google tests should contain Test/Tests at the end which will help the google test adapter to discover the tests. You can also set your own regex to discover tests from
Tools/Options/Google Test Adapter/General in "Regex for test discovery"
You can find more trouble shooting options in Google Test Adapter homepage.
https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter#test_discovery_regex

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: Since version 0.11.0, Google Test Adapter will recognize your gtest executables automagically (but still allows to provide a custom regex as described above).